# How would you count overlapping grain on rice in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-detection, opencv

Given the image provided, how would you use python to count the grains of rice. As you can see, they are overlapping.

Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried this code below, but it failed. I tried: I = cv2.imread("name_of_file.jpg")

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYoRn.jpg)

```html
from sys import argv; from PIL import Image

# Init
I = Image.open(argv[1]); W, H = I.size; A = W * H
D = [sum(c) for c in I.getdata()]
Bh = [0] * H; Ch = [0] * H
Bv = [0] * W; Cv = [0] * W

# Flood-fill
Background = 3 * 255 + 1; S = [0]
while S:
    i = S.pop(); c = D[i]
    if c != Background:
        D[i] = Background
        Bh[i / W] += c; Ch[i / W] += 1
        Bv[i % W] += c; Cv[i % W] += 1
        S += [(i + o) % A for o in [1, -1, W, -W] if abs(D[(i + o) % A] - c) < 10]

# Eliminate "trapped" areas
for i in xrange(H): Bh[i] /= float(max(Ch[i], 1))
for i in xrange(W): Bv[i] /= float(max(Cv[i], 1))
for i in xrange(A):
    a = (Bh[i / W] + Bv[i % W]) / 2
    if D[i] >= a: D[i] = Background

# Estimate grain count
Foreground = -1; avg_grain_area = 3038.38; grain_count = 0
for i in xrange(A):
    if Foreground < D[i] < Background:
        S = [i]; area = 0
        while S:
            j = S.pop() % A
            if Foreground < D[j] < Background:
                D[j] = Foreground; area += 1
                S += [j - 1, j + 1, j - W, j + W]
        grain_count += int(round(area / avg_grain_area))

# Output
print grain_count
```

Comment: Is there any attempt you have tried?

Comment: I have just added a code that I have tried, it does well in other examples to detect the foreground (all the rice) but I can't seem to get it to run on pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complicated question of image analysis. You might train a neural network to count the grains of rice but it is not so easy. You would need  many pictures where you have already counted the grains of rice to train the network.

Comment: Neural network seems possible. There's Image AI, where you train the model but it not really working.